# How to handle parallel ports in win 7 64bit?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, parallel-port

I am trying to use an application that is sending some data to LPT1 and it is working well on winXP but on win7(64bit) i get this exception

```
The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
```

Can i communicate with parallel ports on win7 64bit?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a parallel to USB converter to achieve this.